# Pendrive not being detected in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am unable to see my pendrive in ubuntu.
When i reun `fdisk -l`, i can see my pendrive is connected :

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 16.0 GB, 16008609792 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1946 cylinders, total 31266816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b124a

  Device  Boot     Start        End    Blocks  Id  System
/dev/sdd1 2048    31266815    15632384    b    W95 FAT32
```

Also, `lsusb` logs are below:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0461:4d81 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell N889 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Harsh

Comment: Have you mounted it? `mount /dev/sdd1 /some/directory`

Answer (score 1):

I see you have one partition called /dev/sdd1. What you have to do is mount it. To mount a partition you should do the following:

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /folder/where/you/want/to/mount/it
```

Some times a partition is not able to be mounted by itself.

Comment: thanks for reply.
i have created partition using "gparted"
yeah i have already mounted it in /mnt folder.
but still i can't see it :(
do i have to restart computer or reconnect pendrive?

Comment: Try reconnecting it. Maybe use dmesg to see if there is a problem with your device

Comment: I tried reconnecting pendrive but still its now working :(
Device seems to work fine. Demsg log below :
[ 2749.081953] usb 2-1.3: Product: Cruzer Blade
[ 2749.081955] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 2749.081957] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 4C530099900409103290
[ 2749.082320] scsi14 : usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[ 3200.105922] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 3204.657404] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[ 3204.750146] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567
[ 3204.750151] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumbe

Comment: Do you get any error while mounting the device? Did you do it as root?

Comment: i did as Sudo and no i didn't get any error while doing it.

Comment: Are you sure you have any data on it?. To make sure the device is mounted use "mount" without any parameter. If you successfully mounted the device, the device should come out in the list.

Comment: i have already formatted it, hence there should be no data on the device.
i have mounted without parameter:

sudo mount /dev/sde1 /mnt

do i have to do anything else?
i have tried everything in my knowledge, also have looked into almost every forum but still its not working :(

Comment: wow!! after all these trials nothing was working and now i have restarted my computer, and it seems to work now :)

Thanks for your help!!
Though i am not sure why with restart it worked , any idea??

Comment: @harry, what makes you think it wasn't there?  Do you mean that it didn't show up in some graphical application?  Everything you've shown us suggests there was never an issue.  You had mounted it successfully, therefore it was available.

Comment: @terdon yes, it was not showing on the graphical application i.e. it was not listing in folders or filesystem but after restarting computer ,it came up. Thanks for all the advices :)